# How can I use autoproxy configuration in VLC media player?

Tags: proxy, vlc-media-player, autoproxy

The VLC media player supports streaming from the internet.  However, I'm behind the corporate proxy, and I have an autoproxy configuration.  I don't know the actual proxy I should be using because it changes.

How can I tell VLC media player to either use the autoproxy configuration or to use the IE settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't seen such a feature native to VLC, but, if you're just trying to get the proxy to use, I do have a suggestion you could try.

Browse to:

- http://wpad.department.branch.example.com/wpad.dat
- http://wpad.branch.example.com/wpad.dat
- http://wpad.example.com/wpad.dat
- http://wpad.com/wpad.dat

(EDIT: To clarify, the links above were a suggestion to help the OP determine the address of his corporate proxy. They would need to be modified to reflect the corporate domain, e.g. replace example.com, branch.example.com, or department.branch.example.com with your corporate domain. If you already know the proxy address, this is unnecessary.)

If you get a wpad.dat file, open it in a text editor (it's just a javascript function) and it should list the proxies to use.

```
VLC.exe --http-proxy=myusername:mypassword@SERVERNAME:8080
```

Comment: None of them worked here.

Comment: Then either your proxy file is configured using a manually assigned .pac file, or it is done with Group Policy. Is the connections menu disabled in Internet Explorer or can you check there?

Comment: the wpad links are all dead, however just running `"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" --http-proxy=proxy_name:80 works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As off 2022, you can use a proxy on `VLC` as follows:

`CRTL + P` (open preferences) :

[image]

Select `ALL` at the bottom:

[image]

Click on `Input/Codecs` and search for `HTTP proxy`:

[image]

The proxy format is:

`PROTOCOL://URL:PORT` or `PROTOCOL://USER:PASS@URL:PORT`, i.e.:

`http://myproxy.com:11111` or  `http://user:pass@myproxy.com:11111`

Comment: It is so weird that `http://` is required. I almost want to uninstall this app.

Answer (score 1):

To set the HTTP proxy, you have to go to

```
Tools => Preferences
```

Select "ALL" in the "Show settings" form. Then go to

```
Input/Codecs => Access modules => HTTP(S)
```

Set the required values

Comment: I'm using VLC 3.0.8 on Ubuntu. It doesn't have such option. There's only Auto Re-connect under HTTP(S).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing any track ? There was a feature request for this and I'd read that this was incorporated. Which version are you using?

Comment: Just downloaded the latest version for Windows.  I tried playing some track from Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful : [ProxyCfg.exe, a Proxy Configuration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384069%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Invoked with no parameters specified, it displays the current WinHTTP proxy settings.

This Microsoft utility seems to be able to retrieve the current proxy, and might enable you to write an automatic script for VLC (or do it manually). As I don't have an autoproxy, I can't test it for you.

The utility may not included as a part of your operating system. You can download the WinHTTP 5.1 tools as part of the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

First world problem, but I don't want my account locked out after a mandatory corporate password reset every three months; or to keep my password in a file.

This little script may be of use to anyone who isn't comfortable putting their password in plaintext in an ini file.

Add the following into a file called 'VLCWithProxy.vbs' and replace 'USERNAME' with your work username and 'PATH\TO' with your file path to vlc and enter your password (plaintext I know, but not persisted the same way as in a file) into the prompt.

Run by double clicking or from the command line (with optional play url argument). Type your password into the prompt.

```
if(WScript.Arguments.Count > 0) then
    playurl = WScript.Arguments(0)
end if

strPw = InputBox( "Enter password for proxy:" )

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

'cmd /c /start C:\PATH\TO\VLC\VLCPortable.exe --http-proxy="USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYSITE:PROXYPORT ARGS'
strProgram = "cmd /c start C:\PATH\TO\VLC\VLCPortable.exe --http-proxy=""USERNAME:" & strPw & "@internetproxy.company.com:8000"" " & playurl
objShell.Run strProgram
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can set VLC to the autoproxy configuration, isn't that a Firefox plugin? Also, do company rules allow you to watch internet streams? If not you could get into some trouble :)

Comment: Opera has it, as does IE, which provides it as a service to other apps.

Answer (score -1):

Almost autoproxy: portable VLC has a command line [setting](http://blog.petrilopia.net/software/vlc-proxy/)

`VLCPortable.exe  --http-proxy=proxyserver.address.com:port`

vlc.exe has it too (same parameter).

Make a shortcut which have your proxy settings and use that... it's almost autoproxy :-D

See also http://vsingleton.blogspot.com/2008/04/using-vlc-with-proxy-on-windows.html

Comment: Link does not lead to the advertised software.

Comment: Ok I updated the link